# Google Analytics Cordova Plugin not working with Android Ionic App

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-analytics, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I am trying to get google analytics setup with my ionic Android app using this plugin: https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin.It works fine with my iOS ionic app.

I'm using the 1.6.0 version of the plugin; using commands such as "trackView" or "trackEvent" doesn't record anything to the analytics control panel. I have no console errors and initializing with "startTrackerWithId" using the key is successful.

Running the app on an iOS phone shows up in analytics, but not for android. So not sure what the issue is and why it isn't working only for Android?

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm having exactly the same issue with an app on production at the moment.

Comment: Nope still trying to figure it out unfortunately. Anything start working for you?

Comment: Not yet but I've seen that this might fix it https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin/issues/123#issuecomment-151145095 I'll let you know if it does.

Comment: Thanks, I'd appreciate that!

Comment: hey @MarkWilliams ever find a solution? That link above didn't work for me since my build isn't failing so different issue than addressed there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with version `1.7.4`.
Downgrade to version `1.5.5` did the trick.

You can do it by running `cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-google-analytics` and then `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-google-analytics@1.5.5`

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work for me for android, any other ideas?